# 'deadlock detected' error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, deadlock

I have *deadlock detected* error in my code and don't understand why.

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'  
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/config/environment")

mutex = Mutex.new
threads = []
1.upto(10) do |i|
  threads << Thread.new(i) do |id|
    mutex.synchronize do
      # here I want to take 1 record from "class Product < ActiveRecord::Base"
      Product.first
    end
    # and to do here some stuff with it
    # ...
    # but all I get is
    # ./sandbox.rb:15:in `join': deadlock detected (fatal)
  end
end
threads.each { |thread| thread.join }
```

I use rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2

Comment: maybe 2 threads have a lock on your DB instance?

Comment: but how? my rails server is stopped and i use _mutex.synchronize_ to protect _Product.first_ calls

Comment: To be honest, this is a very weird thing to be doing in rails. What are you trying to achieve with the mutex?

Comment: Full version of code downloads web pages from internet for each product in my database. To make it work i have moved activerecord queries to the main thread but i still don't understand what is wrong with my code exmaple, why it doesn't work :(

Comment: @morr: Are you sure you shouldn't be using something like `Product.find(:first, lock: true)`?